# VS-2010 Plugin to look up keywords on msdn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins

Is there a Visual Studio add-on that can allow to use "Lookup" functionality of keywords just like in the MS Word? Would be pretty cool to have one while learning to code F#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Help configured right, F1 should do this for you. If you want a plugin that can search other sources (like Stackoverflow, etc), you can try [Vingy.](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/00c7a872-32d8-4e9a-a81a-b7adef3eb9e6)